# How to get signed apk for flutter with existing app keystore?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to upload a sample flutter app in place of existing application with same package. How to build signed apk with existing keystore details

Comment: You could do it via command prompt like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60699042/3894304 . Therefore your local.properties and keytore.properties must be correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you generated previous fresh **Signed APK** using **Android Studio** as steps given in bellow link then don't worry.

For more info check this link

[stackoverflow.com/questions/55536637/how-to-build-signed-apk-from-android-studio-for-flutter/60163484#60163484](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55536637/how-to-build-signed-apk-from-android-studio-for-flutter/60163484#60163484)

**Now just follow the following steps to build signed apk with existing keystore details.**

**IMPORTANT**

Before generating Signed APK with existing keystore details make sure upgrade each time your **Flutter Version from pubspec.yaml** file and **Version Code from local.properties** file.

**For example**

If previous flutter version code in **pubspec.yaml** file is

**version: 1.0.0+1**   then change it or upgrade it to the **version: 1.0.0+2** or any other greater number than previous after + sign.

And if **flutter.versionCode** in **Project -> android -> local.properties** is

**flutter.versionCode=1** then change it or upgrade it to the **flutter.versionCode=2** or any other greater number than previous code.
[This Version Code is important while releasing your app on **Google Play Console** with existing app i.e. for release **New Update**]

**After that follow the steps bellow -**

**Step 1:**

Go to in your project & then **Tools -> Flutter -> Open for Editing** in Android Studio as shown below

[image]

Then Select New Window option as shown below

[image]

**Step 2 :**

Wait for while until project synchronization. After that
Go to **Build -> GenerateSigned Bundle/APK...** option from menu bar as shown bellow

[image]

**Step 3 :**

Select **Android App Bundle or APK** Option as per your need. (Android App Bundle is best solution) and click Next button.

[image]

**Step 4 :**

Select **Choose existing...** option to generate **Signed APK with existing keystore details.** (When you upload flutter app in place of existing application with same package.)

Select **Key store path** where your key store file **.jks** file stored. **[The path within your project directory.]** (as mentioned above link)]

Then fill the all options i.e.

**Key store password**

**Key alias**

**Key Password**

and Click **Next** button as shown bellow...

[image]

**Step 5 :**

Select options

**Build variants - release** and

**Signature versions** both **V1 and V2** respectively as shown above screen shot and click Finish button as shown bellow.

[image]

**Step 8 :**

Wait for a while until Gradle Build Running process.

and finally you will get the **Generate Signed APK : (APKs) generated successfully**. from that click on **Locate** option to get Location of your Generate Signed APK File. as shown bellow.

[image]

**That's it you generated Signed APK successfully for update your flutter app in place of existing application with same package.**

Comment: Don't use "Android App Bundle" for Flutter, it will cause crashes on Android 6.0 Xiaomi devices, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36822 .

Comment: Ok and Thnx for advice Mr.Kirill Karmazin

Answer (score 6):

Edit the `AndroidManifest` according to your needs then add in `android/key.properties` the keystore data:

```
storePassword=STORE_PASSWORD
keyPassword=KRY_PASSWORD
keyAlias=ALIAS
storeFile=..\\android.jks
```

then place your *.jks (in this case android.jks) in `android/`

In your `app/build.gradle` add those lines:

```
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("key.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
```

When you build your flutter app with `flutter build apk` a release apk with the given keystore will be generated in `build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk`.