# How to build signed appbundle

Tags: flutter, android-app-bundle

We did flutter version up from 1.00 to 1.7.8, before we created signed apk file by 

`flutter build apk --flavor production`

it will generate signed apk file automatically.

But after we upgrade it to 1.7.8
I tried

```
flutter build appbundle --flavor production
```

when I upload it to google play store ,
it says my app is not signed.

Is there anything else I should do when I try to generate aab file instead of apk file?

I kept the setting like before

```
 signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

I have a file named key.properties to store the value for signingConfig

Comment: Try to create your app via terminal: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60699042/3894304 This will make many things automatically for you.

Answer (score 1):

For uploading `aab` to Google play, you have to first enroll for app signing by Google Play.

Check for details here:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/

> 5. Enroll into app signing by Google Play. Otherwise, you can't upload your app bundle to the Play Console.

Comment: Even though we released this app before, apk file release is different from aab file release?

Comment: No issues, You can still Opt into app signing by Google Play. Check the link which I shared, and see Opt into app signing by Google Play, existing app section.

Comment: When using aab, APK files would be generated via bundle tools, So it's not signed by default.
But, Google play signing takes care of that

Comment: oh, thank you so much, seems we need to enroll for app signing, because release is handled by other team, so we don't know the procedure. Thank you!