# Can't find Open for Editing in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'm new to flutter. I want to open (android)module of flutter to another window. But there's no option visible in java file or any other android file. 
[image: check this image]

here is my flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132, locale en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
[!] iOS tools - develop for iOS devices
 ✗ libimobiledevice and ideviceinstaller are not installed. To install with Brew, run:
    brew update
    brew install --HEAD usbmuxd
    brew link usbmuxd
    brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
    brew install ideviceinstaller
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[!] VS Code (version 1.42.1)
✗ Flutter extension not installed; install from
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: Not understand properly what you want.

Comment: I want "Open for editing in android studio" in flutter's android module like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9p1F.png

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am really tired of this now.

Comment: for window, just create new file(_android.iml) as below.path-> android/[project_name]_android.iml

Answer (score 39):

The problem is caused by missing `.iml` project files. These files are added automatically to the `.gitignore` file but they should not. To fix it:

1. Delete `.idea` folder.
2. Create a new temporary Flutter project with the same name.
3. Copy from the project to your existing project these 2 missing files:

- `[project_name].iml`
- `android/[project_name]_android.iml`

4. Open Android Studio and the problem should be gone.

To avoid it in the future, make sure .iml files are not excluded in the gitignore. There is a [Github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54092) on this topic.

Comment: For me, I just needed to create this file `android/[project_name]_android.iml`. I even left it empty.

Comment: @Hasan El-Hefnawy's solution worked for me

Answer (score 35):

Easiest tip that worked for me:
Create new file under android, give it the following name:

```
[project_name]_android.iml
```

Leave it empty then re-try the option. Works like charm!

Comment: Simple, but very helpful

Answer (score 17):

create a file in android studio inside android name

[project_name]_android.iml

[image]

copy paste bellow code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Dart SDK" level="project" />
  </component>
</module>
```

another solution:
you can copy this file from another app and rename as like  [project_name]_android.iml then paste in your project

Comment: easy to follow steps. great

Answer (score 5):

Got to your project view on the left, then find the folder labeled "android" (it will have your current project name next to it in brackets). Right click, then navigate to `Flutter > Open Android module in Android Studio`.

Alternatively, if you open any file (e.g. `build.gradle`) in that "android" subdirectory, you will see `Open for Editing in Android Studio` at the top right. If you happened to click "hide" on this banner previously, simply restart the IDE. [Source](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/android-studio#android-ide).

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you right click on the Android folder -> flutter? Can you open the Android project from there?

This option has stopped working for me after I allowed Android Studio to generate Android project from the "Android project detected" popup suggestion.

I afraid it messed up something in Android Studio settings. I was able to fix it only after deleting all its settings.
I guess there should be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do it the simple way,
File -> Open -> inside the project's folder, select android, and open it in a different window

Answer (score -1):

If you're not seeing that option, you can try this:

1. Press `cmd + shift + o` and search for `build.gradle` file:

   [image]
2. Once you open it, you'll see `Open for Editing in Android Studio` option at top right corner.

   [image]

Comment: No, that's not happening unfortunately.