# I tried running my flutter app on an Emulator and it showed the following error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom'.
> > Remote host terminated the handshake

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I open the app in android studio for editing and the artifacts are automatically downloaded.

There might be other workarounds but this works for me.

**How to open flutter app for editing?**

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60462318/cant-find-open-for-editing-in-android-studio#:~:text=Got%20to%20your,the%20IDE.%20Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60462318/cant-find-open-for-editing-in-android-studio#:%7E:text=Got%20to%20your,the%20IDE.%20Source).