# After updating Android studio to chipmunk existing project not working

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

Hello friend i am working on flutter project now recently i update my android studio to chipmunk after updating i am unable to run my existing flutter project on android before updating it work image is shown below while they opening xcode module only for ios but not for android and if i created any new flutter project it work on both please check image below and let me know what is issue?[image: here android module is not opening shownn image below flutter icon disable]

[image: xcode module is working for ios]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to the File -> invalid caches and restart. Then  open any file from android folder and when you open any file then you can see hint like open for editing in android studio.

EDIT

create a file in android studio inside android name
[image]

copy & paste bellow code in that file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/.pub" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/.dart_tool" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Dart SDK" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Dart Packages" level="project" />
  </component>
</module>
```

Comment: i tried everything even reset but not working

Comment: did you update flutter plugin for android studio ?

Comment: yes before updating it working yes i also updated the plugin

Comment: like i said i create new project it work

Comment: You can follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60462318/cant-find-open-for-editing-in-android-studio

Comment: this is  working thanks please  post it as answer i will mark it

Comment: @joshua :  Please check edited

Comment: work like charm