# Which Flutter APK to use for installation from apk/release/ folder

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, apk

When I build apk via command

**flutter build apk --spli-per-abi**

It generates 3 apk in: *\build\app\outputs\apk\release* directory

I want to know which of the APKs we will use for uploading on  play store or for installing on different devices.
[image]

In addition to this, few android devices are capable of running apk named **v8a** and few are running **v7a** is there anything to do with building an apk for different versions of android? means I do i need to config SDKs so that It will run on all android versions starting from Jelly Beans 4.1

**Thanks**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to upload the 3 apk files to the Play Store.

When a client download you app, Google will provide the correct apk for the phone making the request.

[image: For reference]

Answer (score 0):

please refer to this post : 
[How to build signed apk from Android Studio for Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55536637/how-to-build-signed-apk-from-android-studio-for-flutter)

it will generate fully signed apk reales and u can upload it to google play store to work on all devices

Comment: There is no option for signed bundle in flutter under build

Comment: android studio sir