# How can I build the apk from android studio from flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, apk

now I'm making an app using flutter and trying to upload the app as internal test on Google play store. I saw people asking how to do it, but could not figure it out...
On the official document, it says "Build > Build > Generate Signed Bundle/APK" and I can generate APK, but I don't see the "Generate Signed Bundle/APK".

[image]

When I select "Build APK" in the picture above, it gives me the message like

> You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm,
>   android-arm64, android-x64. If you are deploying the app to the Play
>   Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce
>   the APK size.
>       To generate an app bundle, run:
>           flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
>           Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
>       To split the APKs per ABI, run:
>           flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
>           Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
>   Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
>   27.9s ✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk (19.2MB). Process finished with exit code 0

Also, I saw this chat ([How to build signed apk from Android Studio for Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55536637/how-to-build-signed-apk-from-android-studio-for-flutter)), but I cannot see "open android module in android studio"
[image]

Even when I opened the android project with different window, I cannot see the option as well..

[image]

it will be really helpful if someone can teach me how to generate the APK from my current situation...

Thank you so much..

Comment: You can upload an app bundle (which is preferred btw) for internal test as well, no need to build APK. To build an app bundle all you need to do is to switch over to terminal (bottom left) and type in "flutter build appbundle". That is if you've previously configured signing , manifest, icons etc. I suggest you read this: [https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `Open Android module in Android Studio` is missing under Tools > Flutter is likely because you're using an older version of Flutter DevTools on Android Studio. You can run `flutter pub global activate devtools` on the Terminal to update the DevTools installed on the machine as mentioned on this [guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/cli#install-devtools).

Answer (score -1):

to build apk use this line in terminal

```
flutter build apk --release --no-sound-null-safety
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?