# How to generate a signed app bundle in Flutter through CLI

Tags: android, flutter, apk, android-app-bundle

I have looked at this link:
[How to build signed apk from Android Studio for Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55536637/how-to-build-signed-apk-from-android-studio-for-flutter)

It does not help because I can't find the `Open Android Module in Android Studio` but I remember generating a signed app bundle a couple months ago through command line. Also is there a reason for that option not coming in my Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Step one: Check your gradle version if its 6.0 and above in  android/gradle/gradle wrapper properties hit save.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

Step two: cd to android

Step 3:type
gradlew SigningReport

Step four:type
flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --
split-per-abi

Comment: okay my gradle is 5.6.2 how can I upgrade it?

Comment: If youre using Android studio, go to android/gradle/gradle wrapper properties and paste code above. distribution...// hit save  and wait..once done it will print welcome to gradle 6.7

Comment: okay so its says that it doesn't recognize flutter as a command

Comment: okay I resolved that but even the command you have written doesn't produce a SIGNED app bundle