# no option for "generate signed bundle/apk" on purchased source code

Tags: android, android-studio, android-app-bundle, app-bundle

Ive bought an app that already exists on the playstore and want to update the app with my admob information but the option for "generate signed bundle/apk" is greyed out and idk what to fix it. That option is not greyed out for apps that I created on my pc so I don't think its an issue with android studio, am I missing something?

Comment: Are you by any chance opening an apk, dex or aab and expecting it to work? Please clarify on what you're trying to open in Android Studio, and be specific. Is it a project that uses Gradle or other recognized build system?

Comment: sorry about that, it is a project that uses gradle, they sent me the full source code of the app that currently runs on the google play store so I know the code works, but for some reason I can't build an app bundle with it

Comment: Not a Studio expert, but it seems to me that it doesn't recognize the project as an Android project. You may need to configure the modules that have to be imported as Android modules (check out the project settings). Screenshots would also help debugging, if that's an option.

Answer (score 1):

If the project is made with Flutter or something using a similar approach you could do as suggested here: [How to build signed apk from Android Studio for Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55536637/how-to-build-signed-apk-from-android-studio-for-flutter)

Shortform of the solution descriped there:

> In Android Studio's tab bar, click on `Tools` and then `Flutter` and then `Open Android module in Android Studio`.

In the newly opended Window the button should now be available and no longer greyed out. If it still isn't, the linked answer also has further ideas to try.