# Signed my flutter app correctly but still release apk not working on some devices

Tags: android, flutter, android-app-signing

I signed my flutter app in Android Studio step by step by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55536637/how-to-build-signed-apk-from-android-studio-for-flutter) and there after following the Flutter's Build and Release instructions. I run `flutter build apk --split-per-abi` and release apk builds but when I try to run that specific architecture app it fails to do so on some devices.

`flutter clean`
`flutter pub get`

ran these commands but still the same. please help I'm stuck with signing for the past 2 months.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1fByAsqQRk. Please watch this video. It's explained properly, i followed these steps and was able to generate proper apk

Comment: Were you able to run on every device that you installed it in? As I had previously signed my app using command line then only after I shifted to sign using AS. So this is my main concern.

Comment: Yes i was able to run on every device and so far no complains from others.

Comment: i followed every step but no it is just not working on some devices. my app is a whatsapp status saver app and it displays statuses to save with a tap on save button. only this part is not showing in the app. and i'm stuck with this . this is my first app that's why i'm having issues.

Comment: When you say your app is not working with other devices do you mean it's not getting installed or it's not working functionally? Please check the minimum sdk version in you gradle also check on which devices it's not working maybe you'll find something common like it works with Android 9 and not working after on Android 10 phones

Comment: Yes it's working on Android 9 but not with 10 and +. Any idea about that?

Comment: Yes, so you need to migrate your project to support Android 10. You would need to download proper SDK and do some changes in your gradles. More info on this topic 
 here https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration . Please keep a backup of your original code, check the pros and cons before you begin

Comment: But my project is already set to API level 30. target SdkVersion is 30. And it's compatible to android x

Comment: okay. Is there an installation error when user tries to install in Android 10 device? or the app is installed but it is not working?

Comment: App is installed but not working. It just shows the appbar with its title. But not the body where the data is present that is the statuses from WhatsApp. In the body it's just plain white body.

Comment: Is it possible to share the source code? Maybe it's some render overflow issue

Comment: here you go https://github.com/theyashjha/status-saver

Comment: So i created an unsigned apk and installed it on my device (OnePlus 6T running on Android 10) , i was able to run it , even the status was saved successfully. Your app is not working on Android 10 only in signed apk version?

Comment: at this point i really think my app is okay but android studio is broken. can you please try that app on android 11? it's not working on my android 11 device so!

Comment: also my app is not working in either case. in android 10 and above.

Comment: Android studio can be a pain sometimes, can you try with VSCode?. Also i don't think it's signed apk issues you must be missing some sdk or libraries in android studo including NDK (side by side). Unfortunately i don't have Android 11 device so can't check

Comment: Is android ndk necessary? I don't have it in my android studio i just have sdk tools and all. So do you think that might be causing the problem?

Comment: No harm in trying to be honest, yes please install NDK i have installed in my machine. maybe it'll help