# Flutter build signed apk or appbundle with code obfuscation

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I was looking for a way to obfuscate my Android APK/AppBundle, then I found [this command](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/obfuscate#obfuscating-your-app):

```
flutter build apk --obfuscate --split-debug-info=/<project-name>/<directory>
```

But it doesn't have keystore information so I can't publish this file on the Google Play Console. Then, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55536637/6618622) for building the app with keys but then it doesn't use obfuscation.

So, how do I build a release version of my app with Dart code obfuscation?

Answer (score 2):

*Obfuscate Code : We have 2 level for obfuscate your code:*

- Obfuscate for native code (Java, Kotlin) , this config will at gradle file. you can read more at:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

- Obfuscate Dart code. (the same with your command)

https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/obfuscate

You can obfuscate both Native Code and Dart Code.

*Build release for APK.*

- If you don't have keystore to sign app, you can create it with this guide:

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Comment: "But it doesn't have keystore information so I can't publish this file on the Google Play Console." 
-> you can create new one. If you already have it, let config on gradle at signingConfigs. (in my attach link).

- "but then it doesn't use obfuscation." -> because they are use GUI. After config key for release on gradle. you can run above command.

Comment: Yes, *it*  meant *command* not *me*. I was talking about the command. The command doesn't allow me to enter keystore information.

Comment: And sorry I didn't understand second part of your comment. You can edit your post to explain it.

Comment: you can config keystore information on your gradle.  you can try with this guide https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328730/how-to-create-a-release-signed-apk-file-using-gradle

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I'll upvote your post for this :)