# how to keystore to jks to sign apk

Tags: flutter

I make an app on kodular. now I want to shift my app in the flutter. I have kodular app sha key & Keystore file. now, how can I use them in the flutter. In flutter, I need key hash for Facebook login & jks file. How can I get this? Please help. how can I migrate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55536637/how-to-build-signed-apk-from-android-studio-for-flutter

Comment: If you properly follow official documentation mentioned in @Siddharth answer, then you can check your config by going into android folder and run command `./gradlew app:signingReport`. It will show you what file/hash you used.