# Play Store Application Installation

Tags: flutter

I've reached the end of my Flutter app. I was able to complete the part of creating the keys and uploading them to the Play Store. After making the key settings in the terminal, I create the .aab file in Android Studio with Build>Flutter>Build App Bunle options. When uploading a version in Play Console,

> You have uploaded a signed APK or Android App Bundle in debug mode. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle in publish mode.

How can I solve this situation?

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore %userprofile%\upload-keystore.jks ^
       -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 ^
       -alias upload
```

I created the key using but Play Console gave an error.

Comment: `Steps--->` 1) Open Android folder into the new window of your android studio then build signed apk from there follow this steps for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/55549073/11404883

Answer (score 0):

**1. Create an upload keystore**

open terminal and run following command:

On macOS or Linux, use the following command:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA \
              -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

On Windows, use the following command in PowerShell:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore %userprofile%\upload-keystore.jks ^
          -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 ^
          -alias upload
```

**2. Reference the keystore from the app**

Create a file named [project]/android/key.properties that contains a reference to your keystore. Don’t include the angle brackets (< >). They indicate that the text serves as a placeholder for your values.

```
storePassword=<password-from-previous-step>
keyPassword=<password-from-previous-step>
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=<keystore-file-location>
```

**3. Configure signing in gradle**

Configure gradle to use your upload key when building your app in release mode by editing the [project]/android/app/build.gradle file.

i.) Add the keystore information from your properties file before the android block:

```
  def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

   android {
         ...
   }
```

ii.) Find the buildTypes block:

```
   buildTypes {
       release {
           // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
           // Signing with the debug keys for now,
           // so `flutter run --release` works.
           signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
       }
   }
```

iii.) And replace it with the following signing configuration info:

```
   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? 
          file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
         
           //signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
```

iv.) Now run the command `flutter build appbundle` now its genrate signed .aab file and upload it on play store for more details check fllowing link

[Flutter Docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android)